# Temporarily clearing untracked files before commit in Git

Tags: git, testing, commit, pre-commit

Whenever I commit, I worry that I may have missed out a dependency and I'm looking for the simplest way to test my git tree in isolation to ensure whatever is in the git index ("staged") will in fact compile/run on their own.

My code's dependencies exist in the filesystem from where I do the 'git add' and so simple compiling and running tests doesn't guarantee that whatever I checkin would compile/run if the tree (or staging area) was checkout out onto a clean filesystem.

I could have a continuous build that would check after submission but I prefer not to have any bad commits in the history that I later have to patch. I therefore want a way of creating an isolated environment that includes a checkout of the tree as well as the index/staging area.

One thing I've considered is using git stash twice, i.e.:

1. Invoke 'git stash' to save the files in the index
2. Somehow get a list of the files not tracked, 'git add' all these files, save a new stash
3. Delete all the previously untracked files
4. Restore the original stash
5. I should now have a clean environment that has only the code already checked-in and the code in the staging area which I can compile & test.
6. Once finished, I restore the stash of the untracked files and then untrack them to leave me in the same position that I was in originally.

(These untracked files may be useful but not necessarily things I want to check in to the repository - e.g. eclipse projects).

I have a feeling I'm overengineering a simple problem, though.

Comment: If you don't want to permanently remove the untracked files, you could just brute-force it by cloning the repo. For your idea, you can get the list of untracked files with `git ls-files --others`, I believe. And if this is temporary, you can always just `git add` them, remove the files, test, `git checkout` them (`git check` them `out`? this copies from the index), then `git reset HEAD` to wipe them out of the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install this script (or something like it -- mine is stolen too) as a pre-commit hook. It copies the index to a temporary working dir and runs a build there. It will catch files that you've missed.

I know there are at least one or two other SO questions that address this exact issue -- testing/validating the index instead of the working dir in a pre-commit hook -- but I can't seem to find them right now.

(For completeness, I've got this script in my repo as .git-hooks/pre-commit/test-the-index; there are a couple of other scripts there. See below for what I'm using as .git/hooks/pre-commit.)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Via: http://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts/blob/master/pre-commit.sh
#

if [ ! $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD) = refs/heads/master ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# These are the locations I keep my temporary source and build trees in
TMPDIR=$HOME/code/myproject-pre-commit
MIRROR=$HOME/code/myproject-pre-commit-mirror

# Exit with status 1 if any command below fails
set -e

# Checkout a copy of the current index into MIRROR
git checkout-index --prefix=$MIRROR/ -af

# Remove files from MIRROR which are no longer present in the index
git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=D -z HEAD | \
    (cd $MIRROR && xargs -0 rm -f --)

# Copy only _changed files_ from MIRROR to TMPDIR, without copying timestamps.
# This includes copying over new files, and deleting removed ones.  This way,
# "make check" will only rebuild what is necessary to validate the commit.
rsync -rlpgoDOc --delete --exclude-from=.git-hooks/excludes $MIRROR/ $TMPDIR/

# Everything else happens in the temporary build tree
cd $TMPDIR

nosetests

exit 0
```

This is my actual .git/hooks/pre-commit:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
for hook in $(find .git-hooks/pre-commit -perm /u+x,g+x,o+x -type f -not -name '*~' 2>/dev/null)
do
  echo "@@ Running hook: $(basename $hook)"
  $hook "$@"
done
```

Comment: [Here's the blog post](http://www.newartisans.com/2009/02/building-a-better-pre-commit-hook-for-git.html) that provides the motivation for the first script in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks that a great answer! I'm also tried to find existing SO queries about this b t couldn't find. Can someone please comment (even answer) with a link to where this is already asked?

Comment: @AshirusNW - I could be wrong about seeing other SO questions on this topic. I may have just seen the blog post linked above and one or two other similar posts.

Answer (score 3):

`git stash -u --keep-index` before test, followed by `git stash pop` after test.

Comment: Wow, this is such a simple and easy answer! Thanks! I just tried it and the only weird thing that happened is that the changes were added to the index when doing `git stash pop` so I had to do `git reset HEAD` to remove them from there and go back to the original state... Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Setup ignore for the important files and simply erase those that are not important `git clean -df`